# How to get a Long typed production of a Seq[Int] in Scala?

Tags: scala

Suppose `val s = Seq[Int]` and I would like to get the production of all its elements. The value is guaranteed to be greater than `Int.MaxValue` but less than `Long.MaxValue` so I hope the value to be a `Long` type.

It seems I cannot use `product`/`foldLeft`/`reduceLeft` due to the fact `Long` and `Int` are different types without any relations; therefore I need to write a for-loop myself. Is there any decent way to achieve this goal?

Note: I'm just asking the possibility to use builtin libraries but still fine with "ugly" code below.

```
def product(a: Seq[Int]): Long = {
    var p = 1L
    for (e <- a) p = p * e
    p
  }
```

Comment: "t seems I cannot use product/foldLeft/reduceLeft due to the fact Long and Int are different types without any relations;" This is wrong. See my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to mess about with `asInstanceOf` or your own loop. `foldLeft` works just fine

```
val xs = Seq(1,1000000000,1000000) 
xs.foldLeft(1L)((a,e) => a*e)
//> res0: Long = 1000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

`def product(s: Seq[Int]) = s.map(_.asInstanceOf[Long]).fold(1L)( _ * _ )`

In fact, having re-read your question and learnt about the existence of product itself, you could just do:

`def product(s: Seq[Int]) = s.map(_.asInstanceOf[Long]).product`

Comment: exactly! i didn't realized that!. BTW,  personally I prefer `toLong`.